# Algolia Remove _highlightResult from search results

Tags: node.js, search, algolia

In the response from a `search` call, I get back a `hits` array and each item in the array includes a `_highlightResult` property. Is there any way to prevent that property from being returned in the search results?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's an option `attributesToHighlight`.

You can use it as an index setting or specify it per search request in the params. By default, all searchable attributes will be highlighted, but if you explicitly set it to an empty array `attributesToHighlight: []`, none will be highlighted.

Please see https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-parameters/attributesToHighlight/?language=javascript